# node_submit fill start/end date field

Tags: 7, nodes

I have the following code:

```
            $node = new stdClass();
            $node->type = 'enterprise_event';
            node_object_prepare($node);
            $node->title = $event->title;
            $node->venue = $event->venue;
```

My enterprise_event content type also has a date field which is a (start_date - end_date) field, but using the devel module it shows that the field is called date.
How can I set the date->start_date, date->end_date values?

Is there something like $node->date->start_date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The db columns for a date field's start and end are `value` and `value2` respectively. The usual method to set them would be:

```
$node->field_date[$node->language][0]['value'] = $from_date;
$node->field_date[$node->language][0]['value2'] = $to_date;
```

Comment: how it should be used when only one date needs to be updated? When there is only single date and I try to update I find that instead of changing the first value it is adding value2